# Не приходят письма на почту

Tags: wordpress

На сайте используется плагин contact form 7, при вводе данных в контактную форму, пишет что письмо отправлено, но на почте ничего нет. Попробовал отправить на временную почту, туда всё приходит. Пробовал через код отправить функцией mail() всё отправляется и приходит, но через функцию wp_mail() письмо отправляется, но тоже не приходит(только на временную почту). В SMTP выбрал стандартный способ через php.

Comment: В спаме тоже нет?

Comment: ни где нет, везде пусто

Comment: Поставьте и настройте плагин WP Mail SMTP.

Comment: В настройках CF7 ошибок нет? И смотри в спаме. А откуда SMTP взялся?

Comment: @KAGGDesign зачем эти костыли? С сервера нормально почта отправляется.

Comment: Затем, что сервер надо уметь настроить. А с шаредов часто возникают проблемы. Потому и существуют эти "костыли" с 3+ миллионов установок.

Comment: Похоже, что у него стоит уже какой-то плагин отправки почты. Только вот в них php - стандартный метод отправки (считай, плагина нет).

Comment: @KAGGDesign ты же шаредами не пользуешься - откуда знаешь? :) Нет таких проблем у них. Ну может у самых отстойных.  К тому же тут явно всё нормально - wp_mail()  работает. А то да кол-ва установок - это  показатель пиара и/или ламерства юзеров, а не причина  необходимости использовать.